# Can not get selectedindex with Listbox in VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I click on items in my listbox and then hit a submit button, but when istep through my button_clicked code it doesn't detect any selectedindex.  All controls are in the same form and there are no panels. Why can't I detect what items were clicked on in the listbox?  Thanks!

Comment: WinForms, WebForms, sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about your page load? Maybe you load your listbox in page load and so every time you click the button it loads items again.

Comment: Doh!..that was it. I wrapped in a "If me.IsPostBack = False then" and now it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you aren't checking if it is a postback. Only load the listbox if it isn't postback.

```
Onload(EventArgs e)
{
  If(!IsPostBack)
  {
    //Your code here...
```